# Draw elbow connector on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to allow user to draw something like elbow connector in MS Word on HTML5 canvas using mouse events.I googled through many sites but didn't found any proper solution.Can anyone please help me with code for this or point out to link if any.
Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, what did you try and where in your code did you run into problems. Please share a fiddle if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw elbow connectors using lines plus a quadratic curve to round the elbow.

For example, you can draw an elbow on the top-left of the canvas from [ x:10, y:100 ] to [ x:75, y:20 ] and having a corner radius of 12 like this:

```
// top-left elbow from 10/100 to 75,20 with corner radius 12
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10,100);
ctx.lineTo(10,20+12);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 10,20, 10+12,20 );
ctx.lineTo(75,20);
ctx.strokeStyle=elbow.color;
ctx.lineWidth=elbow.linewi0dth;
ctx.stroke();
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3cN7b/

[image]

Here's example code for defining and drawing elbow connectors:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var elbows=[];
    elbows.push({
        type:"topLeft",
        start:{x:20,y:120},
        end:{x:120,y:20},
        cornerRadius:12,
        color:"red",
        linewidth:8
    });
    elbows.push({
        type:"topRight",
        start:{x:120,y:20},
        end:{x:220,y:120},
        cornerRadius:12,
        color:"blue",
        linewidth:8
    });
    elbows.push({
        type:"bottomRight",
        start:{x:220,y:120},
        end:{x:120,y:220},
        cornerRadius:12,
        color:"green",
        linewidth:8
    });
    elbows.push({
        type:"bottomLeft",
        start:{x:120,y:220},
        end:{x:20,y:120},
        cornerRadius:12,
        color:"gold",
        linewidth:8
    });

    drawElbows();

    function drawElbows(){
        for(var i=0;i<elbows.length;i++){
            drawElbow(elbows[i]);
        }
    }

    function drawElbow(elbow){

        // starting elbow
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(elbow.start.x,elbow.start.y);

        // middle elbow
        switch(elbow.type){
            case "topLeft":
                ctx.lineTo(elbow.start.x,elbow.end.y+elbow.cornerRadius);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
                    elbow.start.x,elbow.end.y,
                    elbow.start.x+elbow.cornerRadius,elbow.end.y
                );
                break;
            case "topRight":
                ctx.lineTo(elbow.end.x-elbow.cornerRadius,elbow.start.y);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
                    elbow.end.x,elbow.start.y,
                    elbow.end.x,elbow.start.y+elbow.cornerRadius
                );
                break;
            case "bottomRight":
                ctx.lineTo(elbow.start.x,elbow.end.y-elbow.cornerRadius);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
                    elbow.start.x,elbow.end.y,
                    elbow.start.x-elbow.cornerRadius,elbow.end.y
                );
                break;
            case "bottomLeft":
                ctx.lineTo(elbow.end.x+elbow.cornerRadius,elbow.start.y);
                ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
                    elbow.end.x,elbow.start.y,
                    elbow.end.x,elbow.start.y-elbow.cornerRadius
                );
                break;
        }

        // ending elbow
        ctx.lineTo(elbow.end.x,elbow.end.y);
        ctx.strokeStyle=elbow.color;
        ctx.lineWidth=elbow.linewi0dth;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```